# Writing Sebesda's lexical analyzer in python. Does not work for last lexeme in the input file

Tags: python, parsing, analyzer, lexical

I have to translate lexical analyzer the code in Sebesda's Concpets of Programming Languages (chapter 4, section 2) to python. Here's what I have so far:

```
# Character classes #
LETTER = 0
DIGIT = 1
UNKNOWN = 99

# Token Codes #
INT_LIT = 10
IDENT = 11
ASSIGN_OP = 20
ADD_OP= 21
SUB_OP = 22
MULT_OP = 23
DIV_OP = 24
LEFT_PAREN = 25
RIGHT_PAREN = 26

charClass = ''
lexeme = ''
lexLen = 0
token = ''
nextToken = ''

### lookup - function to lookup operators and parentheses ###
###          and return the token                         ###
def lookup(ch):
    def left_paren():
        addChar()
        globals()['nextToken'] = LEFT_PAREN

    def right_paren():
        addChar()
        globals()['nextToken'] = RIGHT_PAREN

    def add():
        addChar()
        globals()['nextToken'] = ADD_OP

    def subtract():
        addChar()
        globals()['nextToken'] = SUB_OP

    def multiply():
        addChar()
        globals()['nextToken'] = MULT_OP

    def divide():
        addChar()
        globals()['nextToken'] = DIV_OP
    options = {')': right_paren, '(': left_paren, '+': add,
               '-': subtract, '*': multiply , '/': divide}

    if ch in options.keys():
        options[ch]()
    else:
        addChar()

### addchar- a function to add next char to lexeme ###
def addChar():
    #lexeme = globals()['lexeme']
    if(len(globals()['lexeme']) <=98):
        globals()['lexeme'] += nextChar
    else:
        print("Error. Lexeme is too long")

### getChar- a function to get the next Character of input and determine its character class ###
def getChar():
    globals()['nextChar'] = globals()['contents'][0]
    if nextChar.isalpha():
        globals()['charClass'] = LETTER
    elif nextChar.isdigit():
        globals()['charClass'] = DIGIT
    else:
        globals()['charClass'] = UNKNOWN
    globals()['contents'] = globals()['contents'][1:]


## getNonBlank() - function to call getChar() until it returns a non whitespace character ##
def getNonBlank():
    while nextChar.isspace():
        getChar()

## lex- simple lexical analyzer for arithmetic functions ##
def lex():
    globals()['lexLen'] = 0
    getNonBlank()
    def letterfunc():
        globals()['lexeme'] = ''
        addChar()
        getChar()
        while(globals()['charClass'] == LETTER or globals()['charClass'] == DIGIT):
            addChar()
            getChar()
        globals()['nextToken'] = IDENT

    def digitfunc():
        globals()['lexeme'] = ''
        addChar()
        getChar()
        while(globals()['charClass'] == DIGIT):
            addChar()
            getChar()
        globals()['nextToken'] = INT_LIT

    def unknownfunc():
        globals()['lexeme'] = ''
        lookup(nextChar)
        getChar()

    lexDict = {LETTER: letterfunc, DIGIT: digitfunc, UNKNOWN: unknownfunc}
    if charClass in lexDict.keys():
        lexDict[charClass]()
    print('The next token is: '+ str(globals()['nextToken']) + ' The next lexeme is: ' + globals()['lexeme'])

with open('input.txt') as input:
    contents = input.read()
    getChar()
    lex()
    while contents:
        lex()
```

I'm using the string `sum + 1 / 33` as my sample input string. From what I understand, the first call to getChar() at the top level sets the characterClass to LETTER and`contents` to `um + 1 / 33`.

The program then enters the while loop and calls `lex()`. `lex()` in turn accumulates the word sum in to `lexeme`. When the while loop inside `letterfunc` encounters the first white-space character, it breaks, exiting `lex()`

Since `contents` is not empty, the program goes through the while loop at the top level again. This time, the `getNonBlank()` call inside `lex()` "throws out the spaces in `contents` and the same process as before is repeated.

Where I encounter an error, is at the last lexeme. I'm told that `globals()['contents'][0]` is out of range when called by `getChar()`. I'm not expecting it to be a difficult error to find but I've tried tracing it by hand and can't seem to spot the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply because after successfully reading the last `3` of input string, the `digitfunc` function iterate one more time `getchar`. But at that moment `content` has been exhausted and is empty, so `contents[0]` is passed end of buffer, hence the error.

As a workaround, if you add a newline or a space after the last character of expression, your current code does not exhibit the problem.

The reason for that is that when last char is `UNKNOWN` you immediately  return from lex and exit the loop because `content` is empty, but if your are processing a number or a symbol you loop calling `getchar` without testing end of input. By the way, if your input string ends with a right paren, your lexer *eats* it and forget to display that it found it.

So you should at least:

- test end of input in getchar:

  ```
  def getchar():
      if len(contents) == 0:
          # print "END OF INPUT DETECTED"
          globals()['charClass'] = UNKNOWN
          globals()['nextChar'] = ''
          return
      ...
  ```
- display the last token if one is left:

  ```
  ...
  while contents:
      lex()
  lex()
  ```
- control if a lexeme is present (weird things may happen at end of input)

  ```
  ...
  if charClass in lexDict.keys():
      lexDict[charClass]()
  if lexeme != '':
      print('The next token is: '+ str(globals()['nextToken']) +
            ' The next lexeme is: >' + globals()['lexeme'] + '<')
  ```

But your usage of globals is ***bad***. The common idiom to use a global from within a function is to declare it before usage:

```
a = 5

def setA(val):
    global a
    a = val   # sets the global variable a
```

But globals in Python are *code smell*. The best you could do is to properly encapsulate you parser in a class. ***Objects are better than globals***